# How to append regex literal with string literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, concatenation

Can i append regex literal with string literal in javascript ?
Like this:

```
var str = "iam 91 old";
var query = 'old';
var reg = /(\d+\s + query +)/;
alert(reg.exec(str)[1]);
```

this cod will be error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a literal.

Use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor :

```
var reg = new RegExp("(\\d+\\s" + query + ")");
```

Comment: can i call this reg.exec() function in this way?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same as `/(\d+\sold)/`